# Is dependency created when adding one variable which is the difference of two existing variables to a regression model?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

I have two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ in linear regression. I would like to see if the distance between $x_1-x_2$ is significant. So I want to add one more variable $x_3$, which is equal to $x_1-x_2$.

But does this generate dependency and thus collinearity? If so, how can I know the effect of the distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly there's complete linear dependence between the existing variables $(x_1,x_2)$ and their difference ($x_3=x_1-x_2$).

One way to see this is that you can write any one of the predictors as a linear combination of the other two. Specifically, $x_3$ is *defined* that way, but you can also write each of the others that way. [See the third paragraph of the Wikipedia article on [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity)]

Note in particular, that if you add some constant $\delta$ to the coefficient of $x_3$ and also add the same constant to the coefficient of $x_2$ and subtract it from the coefficient of $x_1$, the fit will be unchanged.

As a result, you cannot uniquely [identify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability) the parameters in the larger model - any optimal solution is accompanied by an infinity of other solutions.

Without some form of constraint/regularization, you can't estimate all three at once.